# Find the rate at which the surface area is changing when the length of the side is 2

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The volume $V$, the surface area $S$, and side length $x$ of the cube are all varying with respect to time $t$. It is known that rate of change of volume is $1$ inch cubed/second. Find the rate at which the surface area is changing when the length of the side is $2$ inches.

\begin{align*}
S & = 6x^2\\
\frac{DS}{dt} & = 12x~\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{align*}

Comment: S= 6x^2
Ds/dt = 12x dx/dt

Comment: how surface area relates to side?

Comment: Is rate of change equation for surface are correct

Answer (score 0):

The surface area of a cube is $S=6x^2$. Find the derivative w.r.t. $t$
$$
S'=12x\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
From the given, we also have
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=1=3x^2\frac{dx}{dt}
$$

The two equations above are sufficient to find $S'$

Comment: Sorry but I’m new to this and still lost, I know how you got the derivative of S but where did 3x^2 come from and how is the derivative of the volume gonna help me

Comment: @Kdot King the volume of a cube is $V=x^3$ so its derivative with respect to time is $3x^2 \frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: So if I plug in 2 to 1= 3x^2 dx/dt which will give me 1/12 = dx/dt

Comment: @Kdot King yes that is correct. It would be now left to solve for $S'$ given the value of $x$ and $dx\over dt$

Comment: So it’ll be 2 inch^3/second